# css: link image using sliding doors technique

Tags: css

i'd like to add a little arrow image (+hover effect) to all hyperlinks by defining a css class.
my question: would it be possible using the sliding doors technique for that?
the problem with it: i can't set a fixed width for the link (for truncating the image) as the link's text would be ignore that width - any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what the arrow will look like. I don't quiet understand how the sliding doors technique would even be used here.

Comment: i was thinking about 2 arrows side-by-side, 4 pixels wide each.
but i can't crop it down to only 4 pixel width because the links's text will stretch it.

Answer (score 1):

use padding to push the text and put the arrow as background image on the area that the padding is occupying ..

```
a.arrowclass /*the selector could be just 'a' if you wanted it on all links */ { 
  padding-left:20px;
  background: url(/path/to/arrow.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}
```